# Create gap underneath columns within a row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the following code in a website

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="card wow fadeInUp">

                    <!--Card image-->
                    <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
                        <img src="http://mdbootstrap.com/images/regular/city/img%20(2).jpg" class="img-fluid"
                             alt="">
                        <a>
                            <div class="mask"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card image-->

                    <!--Card content-->
                    <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
                        <!--Title-->
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <hr>
                        <!--Text-->
                        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident
                            fuga animi architecto dolores dicta cum quo velit.</p>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card content-->

                </div>
                <!--/.Card-->
            </div>
            <!--First columnn-->

            <!--Second columnn-->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <!--Card-->
                <div class="card wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">

                    <!--Card image-->
                    <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
                        <img src="http://mdbootstrap.com/images/regular/city/img%20(3).jpg" class="img-fluid"
                             alt="">
                        <a>
                            <div class="mask"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card image-->

                    <!--Card content-->
                    <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
                        <!--Title-->
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <hr>
                        <!--Text-->
                        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident
                            fuga animi architecto dolores dicta cum quo velit.</p>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card content-->

                </div>
                <!--/.Card-->
            </div>
            <!--Second columnn-->

            <!--Third columnn-->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <!--Card-->
                <div class="card wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">

                    <!--Card image-->
                    <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
                        <img src="http://mdbootstrap.com/images/regular/city/img%20(4).jpg" class="img-fluid"
                             alt="">
                        <a>
                            <div class="mask"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card image-->

                    <!--Card content-->
                    <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
                        <!--Title-->
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <hr>
                        <!--Text-->
                        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident
                            fuga animi architecto dolores dicta cum quo velit.</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="card wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
                    <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
                        <img src="http://mdbootstrap.com/images/regular/city/img%20(8).jpg" class="img-fluid"
                             alt="">
                        <a>
                            <div class="mask"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
                        <!--Title-->
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <hr>
                        <!--Text-->
                        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident
                            fuga animi architecto dolores dicta cum quo velit.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row top-buffer">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="card wow fadeInUp">

                    <!--Card image-->
                    <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
                        <img src="http://mdbootstrap.com/images/regular/city/img%20(2).jpg" class="img-fluid"
                             alt="">
                        <a>
                            <div class="mask"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card image-->

                    <!--Card content-->
                    <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
                        <!--Title-->
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <hr>
                        <!--Text-->
                        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident
                            fuga animi architecto dolores dicta cum quo velit.</p>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card content-->

                </div>
                <!--/.Card-->
            </div>
            <!--First columnn-->

            <!--Second columnn-->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <!--Card-->
                <div class="card wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">

                    <!--Card image-->
                    <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
                        <img src="http://mdbootstrap.com/images/regular/city/img%20(3).jpg" class="img-fluid"
                             alt="">
                        <a>
                            <div class="mask"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card image-->

                    <!--Card content-->
                    <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
                        <!--Title-->
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <hr>
                        <!--Text-->
                        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident
                            fuga animi architecto dolores dicta cum quo velit.</p>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card content-->

                </div>
                <!--/.Card-->
            </div>
            <!--Second columnn-->

            <!--Third columnn-->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <!--Card-->
                <div class="card wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">

                    <!--Card image-->
                    <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
                        <img src="http://mdbootstrap.com/images/regular/city/img%20(4).jpg" class="img-fluid"
                             alt="">
                        <a>
                            <div class="mask"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.Card image-->

                    <!--Card content-->
                    <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
                        <!--Title-->
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <hr>
                        <!--Text-->
                        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident
                            fuga animi architecto dolores dicta cum quo velit.</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="card wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.6s">
                    <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
                        <img src="http://mdbootstrap.com/images/regular/city/img%20(8).jpg" class="img-fluid"
                             alt="">
                        <a>
                            <div class="mask"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
                        <!--Title-->
                        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                        <hr>
                        <!--Text-->
                        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident
                            fuga animi architecto dolores dicta cum quo velit.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If you will notice the `top-buffer` class on the second row, I have the following CSS styling to make sure it doesn't stick to the top row:

```
.top-buffer{
  margin-top:40px;
}
```

Problem is, when I make the window smaller, and the `col-sm-6` comes into play, the columns in each row are touching each other (bottom touching top) though there is still space between the rows and side of the columns.

Is there a way to fix this Bootstrap 4 Alpha 3?

(Image of problem linked on Google Drive because too large to put on StackOverflow)

col-md-3 picture https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B31QKjAceRGsdGhia2p2aC15dVk

col-sm-3 picture https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B31QKjAceRGsZEZ0OUM2NzdZWUU

Comment: i ran your code in [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/woByWO?editors=1100) and it works fine, i mean there's space between rows. note that space(margin) is between rows and not colums so in col-sm device the space is visible on 4th,5th & 6th,7th column [here](http://i.imgur.com/GRgy2WX.jpg). there is even margin between each columns, since `card` class has margin-bottom of 0.75rem.

Comment: I actually just fixed this error after you commented. It appears that my file did not save when I changed the head to have Bootstrap 4 on it and was stuck on 3.3.7. Thanks very much for your comment, though! can you post your answer so I can accept?